# How do I add "e.g.," into citations in rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, citations

How would I add non-citation information to a citation in an rmarkdown document? Like, if I wanted to add an "e.g.," before a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary strings can go inside the square brackets for citations. So, say, adding `[@MyAuthor2023]` in the rmarkdown document would add "(MyAuthor, 2023)" to the rendered document, then `[e.g., @MyAuthor2023]` would add "(e.g., MyAuthor, 2023)" the rendered document.